# Infered generic is different when a generic type is nested in an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If have this code :

```
type Signal<T> = {};

declare type Animal = 'cat' | 'dog';
declare const animal: Animal;

declare function toSignal<T, U extends T|null|undefined>(
    source: T,
    options: {initialValue: U}): Signal<T|U>;

const foo = toSignal(animal, {initialValue: 'cat'}) 
//    ^? 'Animal | null | undefined

const foo2 = toSignal(animal, {initialValue: 'cat' as const}) // workaround
//    ^? Animal

//////////////

declare function toSignal2<T, U extends T|null|undefined>(
    source: T,
    initialValue: U): Signal<T|U>;

const foo3 = toSignal2(animal, 'cat')
//    ^? Animal
```

My question is why do I get also `null | undefined` in the first example and not an the 2nd one.

The only difference is that the 2nd generic type is nested in an object.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgcwHYEMA2AeAKgPigXigG8BfAbgFgAoagEwgGM0UAnaUSKAQSTgFt0BKAHIGKYMKgAfEbQD2CYZSr0mraAzlIAzsCgpeAtAC5uh9MrqNmbKADMArkgbA4WqMDnxk6bABooAFUoCAAPYAgkWm0oLCkkBzQ0KSd6OzgkCFocAApqKAKobTkHFgYIUyw-fMK5MFctbVMiDLhXdAA1dAcKoJIASlNvVEw4wJxLKk0dPTs5OSFPYfQcg350AJbedrQutB7TUXFhAahqAHpzwqgAPQB+ampp3Xt5gCZFr0QR1fM0TdaOz2BxEYgk+hiz2AAwuV0K90eVEuyJRqMRqhs0EczgaSA8Xx8aDe-iCIXCkWisXiiWSqQg6Uy2TyVGuxVK5Uq1RZhUBcE63V6gUGsG+vjGE0RUNecgAzJ9lkTfut-qDjv1Ydd7kA)

Comment: I don't have an answer but I think [this code](https://tsplay.dev/W46eAN) demonstrates the same issue, a little more explicitly.  You don't need to constrain `U` to `T` to see this, and it's helpful to see exactly what `T` and `U` are inferred as.

Comment: I don't think anyone's written a Stackoverflow question based on one of my tweets before :-) Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following case:

```
function toSignal<T, U extends T | null | undefined>(
  source: T,
  options: { initialValue: U },
): Signal<T | U>;
```

`U` can be either `T`, `null`, or `undefined` and it is used as a property in an object, which means that the passed object can have `null` or `undefined` in that property as well.

Even though in your usage you definitely pass a string as the value in that object, the compiler can't be sure that the object won't mutate and the property won't be the string that you passed, thus you get the `T | null | undefined` at the end.

In the second case:

```
declare function toSignal2<T, U extends T | null | undefined>(
  source: T,
  initialValue: U,
): Signal<T | U>;
```

You pass a string, not an object and a string can't be mutated, since it is a primitive type, thus you see the expected value at the end.

There are at least two available solutions one of which you already used:

1. [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
toSignal(animal, { initialValue: 'cat' as const });
```

Const assertion will turn the object to read-only, and there will be no possibility of `initialValue` being `null | undefined` for the compiler.

2. [const type parameter (available with ts >= 5.0.x)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters)
   Pretty much the same logic as in the first approach, but more elegant:

```
declare function toSignal<T, const U extends T | null | undefined>(
  source: T,
  options: { initialValue: U },
): Signal<T | U>;
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgcwHYEMA2AeAKgPigXigG8BfAbgFgAoagEwgGM0UAnaUSKAQSTgFt0BKAHIGKYMKgAfEbQD2CYZSr0mraAzlIAzsCgpeAtAC5uh9MrqNmbKADMArkgbA4WqMDnxk6bABooAFUoCAAPYAgkWm0oLGkoJAc0NHinejs4JAhaHAAKaigobTkHFgYIUyw-Aqg5MFctbVMiKEy4V3QANXQHCqCoEmqqAEpTb1RMOJlAnEsVa3V7Jxc3JA8vRAmAJn8oTR09YLCIqJiphKSUmTSIDKyc-KpC4tLyyqHCuoadZtbeDrQ3TQvVMwUG1FGsE2vnOMzm+109jkciEnnG6FyBn46ACLTaAKBIJEYgkA30MQRwGGygA9DTCoUAHoAfig1GolKRci2qI2PjQW0x5jQuL+7TgXR6fVE4kkJGp1DpDKgLLZVCAA)

Comment: TIL for the const type parameter, thx !